# Number of milliseconds in IST date format in JS

Tags: javascript, date

I am giving input date and time in IST, but it gives me milliseconds in UTC. How can I get milliseconds in IST.

```
var atPos = "03:00";    
var jsonDate = new Date("2016"+ "-0" + "7" + "-" + "14" + "T" + atPos);
console.log(jsonDate.getTime()); // getting in UTC
```

Comment: You have some big issues. Parsing a string with the Date constructor isn't recommended due to implementation variances. If the string is parsed correctly, it will be treated as "local", i.e. it will use the host time zone offset to create and equivalent UTC time value, so it will only be "in IST" if the host is set to UTC+01:00.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear to me what you are expecting. A function to parse an ISO 8601 date and time with an offset is not difficult (less than 20 lines, there are examples on SO). Nor is it difficult to output date and time values for a specific time zone, regardless of host settings.

If you wish to trust the built–in Date parser (which is not recommended) then you can create an ISO 8601 compliant string that contains an offset of +05:30 (for India Standard Time) and parse that, e.g.

```
var atPos = "03:00";    
var jsonDate = new Date("2016+ "-0" + "7" + "-" + "14" + "T" + atPos + "+05:30");
```

Date time values are UTC per ECMA-262, you can't change that, so when you do:

```
console.log(jsonDate.getTime()); // getting in UTC
```

you will always get a UTC time value. However, if you use that value to create a Date (as in `new Date(timevalue)`), then the result will represent the same instant in time regardless of host settings.

Following is a function to output a date string with any specified offset. If the comments aren't sufficient, just ask. ;-)

```js
/* Return an ISO 8601 long format string with the specified offset
**
** @param {Date} date - date to format
** @param {string} offset - offset as "+hh:mm" or "+hhmm" or "Z"
**                          default is host time zone
**                          if sign is missing, default is "+"
** @returns {string} ISO 8601 extended format
*/
function formatISO(date, offset) {
  function z(n) {return ('0'  + n).slice(-2)}
  function zz(n){return ('00' + n).slice(-3)}
  if (!date) return;
  // Copy date
  var d = new Date(+date);
  // Convert offset to minutes
  var offSign = '+';
  if (typeof offset == 'undefined') {
    offset = date.getTimezoneOffset();
    offSign = offset < 0? '+' : '-';
    offset *= -1;
  } else if (/z/i.test(offset)) {
    offset = 0;
  } else {
    offSign = /^-/.test(offset)? '-' : '+';
    var t = offset.match(/\d\d/g);
    offset = (t[0]*60 + t[1]*1) * (offSign == '-'? -1 : 1); 
  }
  
  // Adjust d to desired offset
  d.setUTCMinutes(d.getUTCMinutes() + offset);
  // Create timezone string
  offset = Math.abs(offset);
  offset = offset? offSign + z(offset/60 | 0) + ':' + z(offset % 60) : 'Z';
  
  // Create string
  return d.getUTCFullYear() + '-' +
         z(d.getUTCMonth() + 1) + '-' +
         z(d.getUTCDate()) + 'T' +
         z(d.getUTCHours()) + ':' +
         z(d.getUTCMinutes()) + ':' +
         z(d.getUTCSeconds()) + '.'+
         zz(d.getUTCMilliseconds()) + 
         offset;
}

console.log(formatISO(new Date()))           // Host
console.log(formatISO(new Date(),'+05:30'))  // IST
console.log(formatISO(new Date(),'-0800'))   // US AKDT
console.log(formatISO(new Date(),'z'))       // UTC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sss  Milliseconds 00 to 999

document.writeln((new Date("2010")).toUTCString()); 

document.writeln((new Date("2010-06")).toUTCString());

document.writeln((new Date("2010-06-09")).toUTCString());

 // Specifies Z, which indicates UTC time.
document.writeln((new Date("2010-06-09T15:20:00Z")).toUTCString());

 // Specifies -07:00 offset, which is equivalent to Pacific Daylight time.
document.writeln((new Date("2010-06-09T15:20:00-07:00")).toGMTString());

// Specifies a non-ISO Long date.
document.writeln((new Date("June 9, 2010")).toUTCString());

// Specifies a non-ISO Long date.
document.writeln((new Date("2010 June 9")).toUTCString());

// Specifies a non-ISO Short date and time.
document.writeln((new Date("6/9/2010 3:20 pm")).toUTCString());
```

Comment: This gives me Tue Jun 14 2016 18:30:00, but it should give me Tue Jun 14 2016 14:00:00

Comment: i dint get you can you plz elaborate

Answer (score 0):

```
store that millisecond into a variable and then use new date function your job would be done
check out this to convert into millisecond 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to display the numbers of milliseconds between a specified date and midnight January 1, 1970.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var d = Date.UTC(2012, 02, 30);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d;
    var milliseconds= document.getElementById(demo);
    var d = new Date(milliseconds);
    alert(d.toUTCString());
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>    
        <p id="demo"></p>    
            <script>
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = new Date("2015-03");
            </script>    
    </body>
</html>
```